# Adding two really large numbers in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to add two really large numbers (say 30 digit long) in C. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char a[30] =  
    { 
        '1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1',
        '1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1'
.   };
    b[30] =
    {
        '8','8','8','8','8','8','8','8','8','8','8','8','8','8','8',
        '8','8','8','8','8','8','8','8','8','8','8','8','8','8','8'
    };
    int i, j, k, carry = 0, sum[1001];
    if(strlen(a) >= strlen(b))
    {
        k = strlen(a);
    }
    else
    {
        k = strlen(b);
    }

    for(i = strlen(a); i > 0; i--)
    {
        for(j = strlen(b); j > 0; j--)
        {
            sum[k] = (a[i]-'0') + (b[j]-'0') + carry;
            carry = sum[k]/10;
            k--;
        }
    } 
    for(i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", sum[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

but it gives me no answer at all. What is wrong with it?

Comment: `strlen(a) >= strlen(b)` Those are arrays or chars not strings. Strings in C need to be NUL terminated. Better way: `char a[] = "888888888888888888888888888888;"`

Comment: Also you are decrementing `k` all the way down, most likely down to zero, the last for loop won't work if k=0

Comment: you don't want to add every digit in `a` (first outer loop) with every digit in `b` (second inner loop). You want to add corresponding digits once.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I changed the way your loops should work and also added some checks to ensure alignment and consistency in case the length of the large numbers change.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <string.h>
    
        int main()
        {
           int temp = 0;
           char *fp ;
           char *sp ;
           char bigger = '\n';
    
           char a[30] =  
     {'1','1','1','1','1','1',
    '1','1','1','1','1','1',
       '1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1',
            '1','1','1','1','1'
      };
        char b[30] =
        {
            '8','8','8','8','8','8','8','8','8','8','8','8','8','8',
            '8','8','8','8','8','8','8','8','8','8','8','8','8','8',
            '8','8'
        };
        
        int i, c, j, k, carry = 0, sum[1001] = {0};
        if(sizeof(a) > sizeof(b))
        {
            k = sizeof(a);
            j = sizeof(b);
            bigger = 'a';
        }
        else
        {
            k = sizeof(b);
            j = sizeof(a);
            bigger = 'b';
        }
        
        c = k;
        fp = malloc(k);
        sp = malloc(j);
        if (bigger == 'a')
        {
            strncpy(fp, a, k);
            strncpy(sp, b, j);
        }
        else
        {
            strncpy(fp, b, k);
            strncpy(sp, a, j);
        }
        
        for(i = strlen(fp); i > 0; i--,j--)
        {
            if(j>0 )
            {
                temp = *(fp+i-1)-'0' + *(sp+j-1)-'0' + carry;
                if(temp < 10)
                {
                    sum[k] += temp;
                    carry = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    sum[k] += temp%10;
                    carry = temp/10;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                temp = *(fp+i-1)-'0'  + carry;
                if(temp < 10)
                {
                    sum[k] += temp;
                    carry = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    sum[k] += temp%10;
                    carry = temp/10;
                }
            }
            k--;
        } 
if(carry > 0)
    printf("%d", carry);
        for(i = 1; i <= c; i++)
        {
            printf("%d", sum[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Small change to the code above to take care of the last trailing carry value if it > 0:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
int temp = 0;
char *fp ;
char *sp ;
char bigger = '\n';

    char a[10] =  
    { 
        '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','1'
  };
    char b[10] =
    {
        '9','8','9','8','9','8','9','8','9','8'
    };
    
    int i, c, j, k, carry = 0, sum[1001] = {0};
    if(sizeof(a) > sizeof(b))
    {
        k = sizeof(a);
        j = sizeof(b);
        bigger = 'a';
    }
    else
    {
        k = sizeof(b);
        j = sizeof(a);
        bigger = 'b';
    }
    
    c = k;
    fp = malloc(k);
    sp = malloc(j);
    if (bigger == 'a')
    {
        strncpy(fp, a, k);
        strncpy(sp, b, j);
    }
    else
    {
        strncpy(fp, b, k);
        strncpy(sp, a, j);
    }
    
    for(i = strlen(fp); i > 0; i--,j--)
    {
        if(j>0 )
        {
            temp = *(fp+i-1)-'0' + *(sp+j-1)-'0' + carry;
            if(temp < 10)
            {
                sum[k] += temp;
                carry = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                sum[k] += temp%10;
                carry = temp/10;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            temp = *(fp+i-1)-'0'  + carry;
            if(temp < 10)
            {
                sum[k] += temp;
                carry = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                sum[k] += temp%10;
                carry = temp/10;
            }
        }
        k--;
    } 
    
    if(carry > 0)
    printf("%d", carry);
    for(i = 1; i <= c; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", sum[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your own answer and don't give two answers.